Navigator.pop(context) isn't working in GestureDetector
How to make Navigator.pop(context) work in GestureDetector?
I think the problem with SingleChildScrollView, but I don't understand how to fix it.
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: greyGood,
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 350,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Image.asset(
                widget.photo,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(


I tried use
setState(() {
          Navigator.pop(context);
});

and tried to replace with
IconButton(
     icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded),
     onPressed: () {
     Navigator.pop(context);
  },
),

but it isn't worked for me

Where is this widget in the widget tree? Is there a parent widget, or are you routing to this widget?

Move SafeArea widget after Positioned in list. The problem is that the Positioned is over SafeArea and gestures was not recognized.
Also instead of pop;, you have to use pop();
